# check for poor internet connectivity android studio

Tags: android

I am using reward ad video in my app. When there is no internet connection, I check it using this function and do not show the ad.

```
public final boolean isInternetOn() {
    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager
            = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    return activeNetworkInfo != null && activeNetworkInfo.isConnected();
}
```

But the problem is, when there is poor connection it takes so much time to show the ad and ad is not shown many times. I want to check for poor connectivity and if connection is poor don't show the ad and show alert for poor connection. How to achieve this?

Comment: try with this -https://github.com/facebook/network-connection-class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define what **slow network** means. I will assume that by the slow network you mean **2G** and **3G** networks. In that case, you can use `subType` of `NetworkInfo` class to identify which type of network the user is currently in and perform the appropriate action.

For example, let say you decided that **2G** is slow, you can identify the **2G** network as follows

```
NetworkInfo network = connectivity.getActiveNetworkInfo();
int netSubType = network.getSubtypeName();
if(netSubType == TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_GPRS ||
    netSubType == TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_EDGE ||
    netSubType == TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_1xRTT) {
  //user is in slow network
}
```

See [TelephonyManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html) class for more such constant values.

Comment: OP asks for internet connectivity in general; that includes wifi.

Comment: @ezio Thanks for your reply! I have added check for 2G and 3G But I have a weird problem. My phone network is TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_LTE but still ads are not loading. Should I add more checks with 4G also?

Comment: Maybe you can try that, I would also suggest that your ad serving system is not returning any error

Comment: Remplace  int netSubType = network.getSubtypeName(); to int netSubType = network.getSubtype();

Answer (score 1):

You could build a simple logic through Java Thread basic specifics, for example this runnable class is what you would use to get and time the connectivity:

```
public class CheckInternetActivity implements Runnable{


    public CheckInternetActivity() {

    }

    @Override
    public void run()  {
        System.out.println("Call...sleep....zzzzZZZZZ");
         try {
            Thread.sleep(3000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
            System.out.println("Call...wake up!"); 
    } 
}
```

and this is a possible basi main method call attempt:

ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();

```
    executor.submit( new CheckInternetActivity() );  
    executor.shutdown();

    System.out.println(executor.awaitTermination(4, TimeUnit.SECONDS));//this gives boolean if you respect given timing rate...
```

So wrapping all up in a pseudo:

```
public class CheckInternetActivity implements Runnable{

    private ConnectivityManager connectivityManager;
    private NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo;

    public CheckInternetActivity(ConnectivityManager connectivityManager, NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo ) {
        this.connectivityManager = connectivityManager;
        this.activeNetworkInfo = activeNetworkInfo;
    }

    @Override
    public void run()  {
        System.out.println("getting internet connection");
        ConnectivityManager connectivityManager
        = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
            NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
            System.out.println("Connected!"); 
    }


}
```

main...:

```
ConnectivityManager connectivityManager;
NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo;

ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();

executor.submit( new CheckInternetActivity(connectivityManager, activeNetworkInfo) );  
executor.shutdown();

System.out.println(executor.awaitTermination(4, TimeUnit.SECONDS));//this tells you how much did it takes...and let you do your move based on this output
if(activeNetworkInfo != null)
    System.out.println( "activeNetworkInfo--->" + activeNetworkInfo.isConnected());
else
    System.out.println( "activeNetworkInfo--->null!!");
```

Let me know if it helps...