# How to determine poor connectivity for a network call in Android

Tags: android, networking

I am currently working on determining a poor network connectivity on Android. Right now I only consider /GET HTTP request. I am currently thinking about 2 solutions:

- Set a relatively longer timeout and have a different thread to measure if 1/2 or 2/3 of the timeout has passed, and notify user of such poor connectivity issue
- Keep my original timeout and add retry mechanism: user will be notified by poor network connectivity if the first request timed out. The second request should have a longer timeout.

Right now my OkHttpClient looks like this:

```java
        client = OkHttpClientProvider.createClient()
                .newBuilder()
                .connectTimeout(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .readTimeout(40, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .writeTimeout(40, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .addInterceptor(new RetryInterceptor())
                .build();
```

I am currently inclined towards the second solution, but I'm not sure if that's a good approach. What should be the approach here?

Comment: This might interest you [FB Network Connection Class](https://github.com/facebook/network-connection-class)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I already looked into that class and the example, but the class only helpful if the HTTP request is successful, since it measures the bandwidth. My question is intending to ask if there's anyway to inform users on the fly that their network condition is poor.

Comment: If that is the case then you may need to check user telephony if on 2g, edge or otherwise, as we can mark those range as poor network. See [this reply](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48475891/8043806) and also [this post](https://android.jlelse.eu/designing-android-apps-to-handle-slow-network-speed-dedc04119aac) for telephony list and speed per sec.